# Kotlin tries to cast a Double to an Int for no reason?

Tags: android, kotlin, generics

Good day,

I am trying to make this code work:

```kotlin
fun <T: Comparable<T>> getExtreme(data: JSONArray, searchKeyword: String, compareValue: T, define: CompareOp): T {
    val tmpFun: (T, T) -> Boolean = when (define) {
        CompareOp.LESSER -> { a: T, b: T -> a < b }
        CompareOp.GREATER -> { a: T, b: T -> a > b }
    }

    var extremeAmount: T = compareValue

    for (hourlyIndex in 0 until data.length()) {
        val dataSet: JSONObject = data.getJSONObject(hourlyIndex)
        val hourlyUvi: T = dataSet.get(searchKeyword) as T
        Log.d("MATH FUNC", "$hourlyUvi")
        if (tmpFun(hourlyUvi, extremeAmount)) extremeAmount = hourlyUvi
    }
    return extremeAmount
}
```

But for some reason it always throws this exception:
[image: Exception thrown by Android Studio]

I think what the error is, is that each time it reads a whole number it automatically converts it to an Int instead of staying with my specified T. This code works fine and pretty much flawlessly without this line:
`if (tmpFun(hourlyUvi, extremeAmount)) extremeAmount = hourlyUvi`
If that is the error, how do I enforce my T instead of its own definition, and why is it doing it, or does the error lie anywhere else?

Comment: You are calling `get()` on a `JSONObject`. The object returned by `get()` will be of whatever type `JSONObject` wants, and `JSONObject` knows nothing about `T`.

Comment: I'm aware though I cast it as T and T is throughout this scope the same, so it doesn't make sense that it tries to cast as a Double and then as an Int in the same function call, like it is shown in the pic.

Comment: My guess is that you're seeing some impacts of compiler optimizations in terms of where the exception is thrown. My point is that your use of `get()` is time bomb, as `get()` and `T` are not always going to line up. `JSONObject` is from a 20-year-old JSON parsing library -- have you considered using a more modern JSON parser, such as Moshi?

Comment: You're casting as `T` but it **isn't** a `T` - if the `get()` function parses the string as an `Int`, then that's what the object `is`. All casting it to `T` does is make your code *assume* it's a `T`, it doesn't make it one if it isn't already. Look at your stacktrace - your function says ``hourlyUvi`` and `extremeAmount` are both `Double`s, and then does a basic comparison on them. But the compare function that's called is `Integer.compareTo`, because that's what the first variable ``is``, so that's *how it compares itself to other objects*, y'know?

Comment: There are a bunch of `JSONObject` `get/opt` calls that parse as a specific type, or you could use `getString` and parse it to the type you need yourself. The trouble is that doesn't fit with generics very well, even if you limit `T` to `Number` types. You're probably gonna have to do some type checking for the specific types you want to handle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several built-in type converters like `jsonObj.getDouble(key)` or `jsonObj.getInt(key)` which will appropriately handle conversions when the JSON input string is a numeric type like an integer and you want a different numeric type as an output (e.g. double).

However, using this with a generic output type T is not as straightforward. If you really need to use the generic, you can write a generic JSONObject to T converter. If the JSBONObject is not a numeric type or a string that can be parsed to a numeric type, the `getX` methods will throw.

Make sure the converter covers all the possible numeric types you want to use, or it will fall to the last case and return the test value. You have to pass in an object of type T for the type checking, even if it is unused.

```kotlin
fun <T> jsonObjToType(o: JSONObject, arg: String, test: T): T {
    return when(test) {
        is Double -> o.getDouble(arg) as T
        is Int -> o.getInt(arg) as T
        is Float -> o.getDouble(arg).toFloat() as T
        is Long -> o.getLong(arg) as T
        else -> test // will never hit this as long 
                     // as all possible T types are covered above
    }
}
```

and use it in your function

```kotlin
val hourlyUvi: T = jsonObjToNumericType(dataSet, searchKeyword, extremeAmount)
if (tmpFun(hourlyUvi, extremeAmount)) extremeAmount = hourlyUvi
```

**Note**: when you use Int or Long types, if there are floating point values in the array they will be truncated to an integer value. In almost all cases it is probably better to just write this function for doubles rather than as a generic of `T` to appropriately handle all cases.